# Cross tab Query: Sort Column Heading based on other column Sort order

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a report based on a cross tab query and would like to
 Sort the column heading of the report based on the sort order of
 another field.
 I have three tables called survey results, survey questions and survey
 response choices. Survey response choices has over 800 choices types.
 Survey results capture results of all the surveys and has questions,
 respondent, response choice, response, responsechoice order which
 looks like this
 Question Respondent Questionchoice Response Responseorder

1 1 Agree 20%
 2
 1 1 Strongly Agree 10%
 1
 1 1 Disagree 30%
 3
 1 1 Strongly Disagree 10%
 4
 and so on. With the help of this group I could create a report where
 column heading values change based on the question. My problem is user
 wants to see the result set in response order they have identified. In
 this case:
 Quesion 1 Respondent 1
 Strongly Agree Agree Disgaree Strongly Disagree
 10% 20% 30% 10%
 and so on. The order keeps on changing based on the user input for
 Response order.
 Since there are over 800 response choices I can not put the response
 choices in the Pivot of crosstab query sql view.
 Any help would be appreciated.